# Tomcat wouldn't create access logs anymore - AccessLogValve

Tags: java, logging, tomcat7, server.xml

Below is my logging configuration from **server.xml**  I'm trying to debug something and really need access logs. Tomcat stopped creating access logs suddenly, despite the valve attribute being configured. Any pointers?

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
<Context docBase="agilefant" path="/agilefant" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:agilefant"/>
</Host>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like your Tomcat is starting under Eclipse. In this mode, the access log will be generated in folder `$WORKSPACE_HOME\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs\` instead of `$TOMCAT_HOME\logs\`. (**tmp0** may be different if you have multiple server.)

Comment: @goKishore, I update answer again. The folder is under `$WORKSPACE_HOME` , not `$ECLIPSE_HOME`.